# Rails javascript signin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sign

My signout code in view :

```
      <%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
```

Controller :

```
      def destroy
     if user_signed_in?
     user_sign_out
   end
 redirect_to root_url
```

end

Problem is it is working perfectly if I have JavaScript turbo links like this:

```
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

But when I remove the above line sign out form gives me this error :

```
      No route matches [GET] "/logout"
```

I want to remove the above js link and keep my sign out function working. How do I do this??

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Delete links (including /logout) won't work without javascript support.

Comment: If you want to remove turbolinks only follow the instructions [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4)  specifically the 3rd line says not to remove the whole line just the part data-turbolinks-track => true